# In Nodejs, how to have individual "allowed methods" for each express enpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I am building a rest API with `nodejs` and `express`.

I am trying to implement a small CORS system to the endpoints:

**cors.js**

```
export const cors = ({ allowedMethods }) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    if(!allowedMethods.includes(req.method)){
      return res.sendStatus(405);
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

---

**server.js**

```
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.post('/', cors({allowedMethods: ['POST']}), (req, res) => {

})

app.put('/photo', cors({allowedMethods: ['PUT']}), (req, res) => {

})
```

Let's say I have these 2 endpoints, every time I go to a URL with an unallowed method, I get a 404 response but I want "405 Not Allowed". (makes sense, because of `app.<method>()`)

**How is it possible to look up the `allowedMethods` for each endpoint and decide what to do next?**

I've tried using `app.use(cors())`, but that catches all endpoints and I'll never know about the `allowedMethod` specified for a specific endpoint. And I don't think that [node cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package would do it.

Comment: Where do you want to lookup `allowedMethods`? The `req` or `res` object in the route handler?

Comment: Your middleware is working just fine for me, so there's something else causing your app to return a 404.

Comment: @caTS I want to loop the `allowedMethods` anywhere as soon as I can have access the method allowed for a specific endpoint. For instance, if a user make `post` request in `/photo` it should say **<not allowed>**, not 404. And the same goes when the user make a `put` to `/`... Basically the way it is now, works for the project globally, whereas each endpoint may (un)allow some methods.

Comment: @robertklep it works of course, but how to restrict access (Displaying "Method now allowed") for some methods based on `allowedMethods` specified in the endpoint itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're conflating two different things here.

CORS has a mechanism for stating what HTTP methods are allowed to be used to make a cross origin request from JavaScript which is used in combination with a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

HTTP has a mechanism to say that a request is using an HTTP method that is not allowed at all.

---

Since you are attempting to generate 405 Not Allowed responses, you are dealing with the latter. This has nothing to do with CORS and should be kept separate from CORS middleware.

[`all`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.all) will match all requests for a path, no matter what HTTP method is used, so you can write:

```
const method_not_allowed = (req, res) => {
    return res.sendStatus(405);
};

app.post('/', cors(), (req, res) => { });
app.all('/', method_not_allowed);
```

Any POST request will get caught by `app.post('/'` and any other request to `/` will carry on and get matched by `app.all('/')`.

---

That said, it looks like you are reinventing the wheel and could just use [this existing module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ez-405).

---

If you need to also deal with [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) then you need to take care of that separately.

That does need to be handled with the rest of your CORS logic, and you need to handle both the methods you want requests to be made with (`post` in this example) and OPTIONS (for the preflight).

Comment: That's interesting to know. Maybe I can wrap the endpoint with `app.options()` to handle the preflight and at the end `app.all("/")` to disallow unallowed methods. `app.post()` will be in the middle.

Comment: @Lemayzeur — Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a bit of configuration:

```js
const routes = {
    "/": {
        get: (request, response) => { ... },
        post: (request, response) => { ... },
    },
    "/photo": {
        put: (request, response) => { ... },
    },
};

app.use((request, response, next) => {
    const route = routes[request.url] || {};
    if (!Object.keys(route).includes(request.method.toLowerCase())) {
        return response.sendStatus(405);
    }
    next();
});

for (let route in routes) {
    for (let method in routes[route]) {
        app[method](route, routes[route][method]);
    }
}
```

Even though you'll get in trouble soon with request params (`/photos/:photo_id`).

EDIT: didn't know about `app.all`, much cleaner!